# QGIS the data source manager window will not open

Tags: qgis

When I try to open a vector (Shape) file, the data source manager window will not open. This started happening with an earlier version I was using (3.10) after months of working OK, but the problem continues with a newly installed version (3.16).
I'm using a 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor, Windows 10.

Comment: Is it maybe opening on a different screen?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Heikki. Howver, if that's the case they've done a good job of hiding it. Where could I find/open it? I think it might be better to do a full wipe and re-install.